# Error while accessing Publish in Visual Studio 2019 ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

While publishing ASP.NET project locally I got the error shown below.

[image]

I tried to folder or FileShare.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__3()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__202.MoveNext()
>
> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
>
> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

Comment: Did you look at the Output window? Is anything relevant displayed there?

Comment: What is written in that `.tmp` file?

Comment: application has been successfully working but publish not,
A diagnostic log has been written to the following location 
tmp3FE8.tmp

http://prntscr.com/pecv6b

Comment: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()